# multi dimensional list - vb

Tags: vb.net, list

I have a problem that can't solve...

I have the set of data, which i want to add in two dimensional list (in Visual Basic)

the result of sql query is:

```
ID   value1 value2
0001  a      10
0001  b      10
0002  a      30
0002  b      20
0002  c      15
0003  a       5
```

....

so, i want add all elements into two dimensional list:

```
    Dim multilist As New List(Of List(Of String))
    multilist.Add(New List(Of String))
    multilist.Add(New List(Of String))
    multilist.Add(New List(Of String))
```

and I need a vb code that will add elemenets with different ID's  to different lists of one two dimensional list

thank you :)

result must be:

```
in first list elements 1 and 2
in the second list elements 3,4,5
in the third list the last element
```

Comment: _"different lists of one two dimensional list"_ ??

Comment: You should store that in a datatable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a `DataTable` instead, then you just have to use a `DataAdapter` to fill it and `Linq-To-DataSet`  to get your ID-Groups and `List(Of DataTable)`:

```
Dim table = New DataTable()
Using con = New SqlClient.SqlConnection("Connection-String")
    Using da = New SqlDataAdapter("SQL-Query", con)
        da.Fill(table)
    End Using
End Using

Dim idGroups = From row In table
               Let id = row.Field(Of String)("ID")
               Group row By id Into Group
Dim idTables As List(Of DataTable) = idGroups.
    Select(Function(x) x.Group.CopyToDataTable()).
    ToList()
```

Since you are using .NET 2 LINQ is not an option. Here is an approach using a `Dictionary` instead of a `List` where the key is the ID and the value is the `DataTable`:

```
Dim idTables As New Dictionary(Of String, DataTable)
For Each row As DataRow In table.Rows
    Dim id As String = DirectCast(row("ID"), String)
    Dim dt As DataTable = Nothing
    If Not idTables.TryGetValue(id, dt) Then
        dt = table.Clone() ' empty table with same schema '
        idTables.Add(id, dt)
    End If
    dt.ImportRow(row)
Next
```

This does not require the resultset to be ordered by the ID.

Comment: can you write this code in .NET 2.0 ? this don't works, this is for .NET 3.5 or higher...

thank you :)

Comment: @user1562652: i have provided an apporach for .NET 2.

Comment: but in dictionary, the key is unique, so, I can have only one element with ID = 0001....

Comment: Thats why the value is a DataTable which contains all rows with this Id. I thought this would be your requirement.

Comment: @user1562652: note that you can either access the tables via their ID (if you know it) or by looping the dictionary in a `foreach` where each entry is a `KeyValuePair<string, DataTable>`.